# Django cannot find images under templates

Tags: django

So I am creating a Django project and put an image on an HTML page. Issue is that the server cannot see it.

This is my folder structure: `mysite/app/templates/app/img/pic.png`

The HTML page is in: `mysite/app/templates`

I tried many different scr formats, such as: `<img src="../app/img/pic.png">` but it did not work.

Comment: see this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `STATICFILES_DIRS` to add the folder that you want, or try to put all the static in a folder and reference it in `STATICFILES_DIRS`, like this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
    '/var/www/static/',
]
```

- the first url will be `<the root of your project>/static`
- the second url will be that exactly.

For more info you have the docs right here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#managing-static-files-e-g-images-javascript-css